# Method to move an object from point(x1,y1) to point(x2,y2) at a given speed in a straight line in java

Tags: java

I have to write a method that moves an object (e.g. circle) in a straight line from one coordinate to another with a given speed. The object must get to the target point and stop. The speed correlates to the time in which it takes the object to reach the point (speed = 15 is equivalent to time = 15 ms for example). If someone could help me with the maths here, I would be garateful, please.

Answer (score 8):

The interpolation formula for moving from point p0 to point p1 at constant speed is:

```
p(t) = p0*(1-t) + p1*t
```

where `t` is time that has been scaled to vary from 0 at the start to 1 at the end and `p`, `p0`, and `p1` are (x,y) coordinate pairs. Since Java doesn't have a built-in way to write the interpolation formula, you just apply it to the x and y components in parallel. The result is:

```
t = (time_now - start_time) / total_time;
x = x0*(1-t) + x1*t;
y = y0*(1-t) * y1*t;
```

This is the core calculation. To get the object to move, you follow these steps:

1. [Given: start_time, total_time, x0, y0, x1, y1]
2. put the circle at (x0, y0) and set time_now = start_time
3. until time_now == start_time + total_time, calculate (x, y) using the above, move the circle to (x, y), and increment time_now.

The time increment can be regular wall-clock time as determined by `System.getTimeMillis()`.

Comment: ++ You might want to put a little sleep into the loop, or maybe drive it off a timer event. Also use >= for the time comparison, because == might be missed.

Comment: Good points. The edge effect when the increment takes you past end_time needs to be considered...you don't want to overshoot the end point just because time marched past end time.

Comment: @TedHopp do you have the same equation but with velocity instead of time? thanks in advance, I can make post if you want

Comment: @JSmith - A separate post might be better. Include a detailed description of what you are trying to accomplish. I'm not sure what you mean by velocity instead of time.

Comment: @TedHopp [here is the link to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68379020/how-to-move-an-object-from-one-point-to-another) many thanks in advance